# How do you compare Last-Modified date to file Last Modified date?

Tags: java, date, http-headers, timestamp, last-modified

I am trying to compare the date from the HTTP Last Modified header and to the requested file's last modified date.

I am using Tamper Data plugin in Firefox to add a Last-Modified header to test this and with the date: `"Wed, 09 Apr 2008 23:55:38 GMT"` and for the file I am using `file.lastModified()`.

I then convert file.lastModified into a Date object  and then try to convert the request Last Modified date string into a Date but I get this error: `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: " Wed, 09 Apr 2008 23:55:38 GMT"`

```
Date fileDate = new Date(fileLm);
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
Date requestDate = format.parse(lmRequest);

System.out.println("this is filedate: " + fileDate);
System.out.println("this is requestdate: " + requestDate);
```

Be great if someone can help me. I can't figure out what's wrong :(

Comment: Does your date start with a blank space " Wed, 09 Apr 2008 23:55:38 GMT" ?

Comment: That's one thing I don't get as well. I am pasting in "Wed, 09 Apr 2008 23:55:38 GMT" into the firefox plugin ...

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I added a space onto the SimpleDateFormat " EEE, dd MM....." and it works but I don't know why a space is added onto it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(" EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
```

should work. It works here for me.

The extra space might have something to do with the way xml is formatted.